# Java DeploymentRuleSet and jnlp jre version

Tags: java, java-web-start

Ok,

So we have built and deployed a DeploymentRuleSet.jar to the pcs running our java webstart application with

```
    <ruleset version="1.0+">

     <rule>
       <id>
         <certificate hash="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
       </id>
       <action permission="run"/>
     </rule>

   </ruleset>
```

on our jnlp we have 

`<j2se version="1.8.0_60" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="1024m"/>`

PCS with java 8u40 installed still run the application with u60

Is it possible to make jws use whatever version is specified in the jnlp downloading the required version if needed?